# Reducing webpack bundle size when using ether.js

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-4, truffle

I am building a simple truffle dapp and was wondering how I can further reduce my bundle size using nuxt.

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
```

Like is there a way to import only the functions I need from the ethers to further reduce bundle size.

https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/getting-started.html

Comment: Some standard ways to reduce bundle size include lazy loading ethers, might be appropriate here, using the dynamic import function, refactoring your code, dont think you need ethers right away on mount.